# ReferenceError: window is not defined , angular6 universal

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, angular-universal

I have an angular6 universal application, I am integrating **ng-simple-slideshow** for the image  slider, it's building successful, but while running:
**npm run serve: SSR**  giving below error: please suggest some solution.thanks

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:247023:8032
at vt (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:246852:163)
at Object.module.exports (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:246852:177)
at __webpack_require__ (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:20:30)
at Object.jspdf (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:87271:18)
at __webpack_require__ (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:59361:30)
at Object../src/app/presentation/presentation.component.ts (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:81159:13)
at __webpack_require__ (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:59361:30)
at Object../src/app/presentation/presentation.component.ngfactory.js (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:81046:11)
at __webpack_require__ (F:\new_trd_back_up\dist\server.js:59361:30)
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830

Comment: code that will try to use window will fail because the window is only defined in the browser - when running on Node window will be undefined.build your app with npm run build and host your static files somewhere

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
This answer and question are wrong from the root, Angular uses Domino these days anyways and you should use Injection or Guards, for further explanation, [read the manual](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md#window-is-not-defined).

This also can be solved by using Dominos.

Add this to 'server.ts':

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

Ticket's issue and suggestion on [Github](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-345228799)

Comment: Just tried this but it didn't work with angular 14. Could anyone else also confirm?

Comment: Still works on angular 14, however they did changing in Angular 16 that might break or obsolete this code but I haven't upgrade my projects to v16 yet.

Comment: I have update my angular app from angular 11 to angular 14 and then added nguniversal package. With ng serve --open the app opens up just fine but as soon as I run npm run dev:ssr I get a "window is not defined error". To fix this I added the domino package and added the code from your answer at the start of the server.ts file. But I'm still getting the exact same error. It's been 3 days since I am stuck on this issue. Any advice is appreciated @Remy

Comment: I have updated my answer. Look at their last resort suggestion. @Rahul

Comment: Thank you, trying with the updated answer now.

Comment: Upvoted because it still works.

Answer (score 2):

"window is not defined" came from 3rd party library which accessing window variable.

You should wrapping your code with browser check condition

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isBrowser">
    <!-- In my case, ngx-siema & ngx-slcik -->
    <ngx-siema></ngx-siema> 
</ng-container>
```

**TS:**

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

isBrowser;

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) { 
   this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
}

if (this.isBrowser) { 
  // put your code which is access window variable 
}
```

A good example of usage could be found [here](https://www.ryadel.com/en/angular-5-use-localstorage-window-document-and-other-browser-types-angular-universal/).

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I find which package or file is using window method? I've been trying to fix this issue for days but I couldn't find anything that helped.

Answer (score 2):

With NestJS you can it by simply applying the `applyDomino`, like so:

```
import { AngularUniversalModule, applyDomino } from '@nestjs/ng-universal';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

// Get working directory of client bundle.
const BROWSER_DIR = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/apps/browser');

applyDomino(global, join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index.html')); // Mock document, window etc.

@Module({
  imports: [
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
      bundle: require('./../functions/dist/apps/server/main'), // Bundle is created dynamically during build process.
      liveReload: true,
      viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR
    })
  ]
})
export class AppNestModule {}
```

**Edit:** after upgrading from `Angular 8` to `Angular 10` it stopped working, which you can realise based on [#451](https://github.com/nestjs/ng-universal/issues/451). As of now, the raw `domino` has to be used in such a form (`server.ts`):

```
import { createWindow } from 'domino';
import { join } from 'path';
const indexHtml = join(
  process.cwd(),
  'dist/apps/browser/index2.html'
);
const win = createWindow(indexHtml);

// Polyfills
(global as any).window = win;
(global as any).document = win.document;
(global as any).navigator = win.navigator;

import { ApplicationModule } from './app.module'; // IMPORTANT: MUST be placed AFTER all the code above
```

More detailed answer [#830 (comment)](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-770369651).